# How to use jQuery File Upload (Basic Plus UI version)

Tags: jquery, file, upload

I am trying to use jQuery File Upload plugin (Basic Plus UI version) in my JEE projet, and  I followed these instructions below:

> Using jQuery File Upload (UI version) with a custom server-side upload handler
>
> 1.Implement a file upload handler on your platform (Ruby, Python, Java, etc.) that handles normal form based file uploads and upload it to your server. See also the Server-side specific tutorials on the Documentation Homepage.
> 2. Download and extract the plugin archive.
> 3.Edit main.js and adjust the url option to the URL of your custom file upload handler. Alternatively you can remove the url option and edit index.html and adjust the action attribute of the HTML form element to the URL of your custom file upload handler. If your upload handler requires another parameter name for the file uploads than files[], you also have to adjust the file input name attribute or set the paramName option (see Options documentation).
> 4. Upload the jQuery-File-Upload folder to your website.
> 5. Extend your custom server-side upload handler to return a JSON response akin to the following output:

Now about the step 3

> 3.Edit main.js and adjust the url option to the URL of your custom file upload handler.

As I am using Apache Tomcat 7.0.34.0 on Netbeans, what should I edit in the main.js file?

Here is the main.js file:

```
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin JS Example
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

/* global $, window */

$(function () {
'use strict';

// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: 'server/php/'
});

// Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
$('#fileupload').fileupload(
    'option',
    'redirect',
    window.location.href.replace(
        /\/[^\/]*$/,
        '/cors/result.html?%s'
    )
);

if (window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io') {
    // Demo settings:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
        url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        maxFileSize: 999000,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
    });
    // Upload server status check for browsers with CORS support:
    if ($.support.cors) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
            type: 'HEAD'
        }).fail(function () {
            $('<div class="alert alert-danger"/>')
                .text('Upload server currently unavailable - ' +
                        new Date())
                .appendTo('#fileupload');
        });
    }
} else {
    // Load existing files:
    $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
    $.ajax({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
        dataType: 'json',
        context: $('#fileupload')[0]
    }).always(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
    }).done(function (result) {
        $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
            .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
    });
}

});
```

Thanks